# Populating Birt through columns

Tags: birt

I have been trying to come up with a birt report to print food tag to no avail. What i want to show on the report is:

foodtag1 | foodtag2 | foodtag3

foodtag4 | foodtag5 | foodtag6

foodtag7 | foodtag8 | foodtag9

Can this be done?

the data is taken from a MySql Query "select dishes.name
from dishes
where find_in_set (dishes.id,(select orders.dishes from orders where orders.id = ))"

** Note: FoodTags 1-9 are all unique name of dishes
** Also note that foodtag 1-9 are representatives of a dish name. FoodTag1 can be "Yang Zhou Fried Rice", it can be "italian Pasta". it can be "Mee Goreng". Data is taken out from a datasource in MYSQL server

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  But it is unclear how from your example how you would know that row 2 column 3 is foodtag 6.

Comment: simple it just show foodtag6 if not empty. if foodtag6 is empty, foodtag7, 8 and 9 will be empty

Comment: You are assuming that others will have a familiarity with your data. If foodtag1 is column name then there is one solution, if foodtag1 is a value in the same column as foodtag2 there is different solution.

Comment: ok sorry i edit the example. Foodtag 1 - 9 are not column names, all are unique dish names.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way--

- Drag a grid element to your report, set it at 3 columns and 3 rows
- In property editor, bind the grid to the data set
- Drag a dynamic text element to the first cell in the grid

Then use JavaScript simular to this to filter to the desired text.

```
if (row["FoodTagColumn"]=='foodtag1'){

   row["FoodTagColumn"]

}else null
```

Comment: what if the food tag is more than or less than 9? it is queried from a datasource. I cant possibility hard set it to a grid of 3 rows x 3 columns. if there are only 6 dishes for example, it needs to be smart enough to show 2 rows

Comment: This comes back to you assuming others understand your data. You only mentioned 9.  But.. the 'else null' will not display anything.  So unless you add lines to the grid nothing will display when there is nothing to display.

Comment: ok i see. I'm sorry i am poor at explaining. but another question is why row["FoodTagColumn"] == 'foodtag1'? foodtag1 - 9 is just an example, an representation of a dish. It can be "Yang zhou Fried Rice", it can be "italian pasta". Hence i cannot hard code the term FoodTag 1. BTW i edit my question again. Hope you understand why i generalise my question cos the use case is targetted to a restaurant in Asia, and actual dish name may not be understandable for others who review my question.

Comment: Again you are asking questions about how to manage your data when you have given no helpful descriptions of it.  But yes you can hard code foodtag1, you need some logical way to define your values  adding a column to your data table with foodtag1 or something similar would be a start.  If you really have 'Italian Pasta' and 'Fried Rice' you will probably want a culture field also as I doubt they are side by side on the menu.  This is probably my last comment on the subject, as we are getting into [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)